# change color of selected tag after posting page

Tags: css, html

I have some tags.

```html
<a class="aclass" href="~/product/explain?id=1">item1</a>
<a class="aclass" href="~/product/explain?id=2">item2</a>
<a class="aclass" href="~/product/explain?id=3">item3</a>
```

I want that when a user clicks on any tag, its color will change to red.
I wrote below the code. But when page posts, tag will lose its changed color(red).

```js
    //$('.aclass').click( function (e) {
    $('.aclass').live("click",  function (e) {
        $('.aclass').css("color", "#47b2ed");
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
```

style.css:

```css
    .aclass {
        color: #47b2ed;
        text-decoration: none;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 //$('.aclass').click( function (e) {
$('.aclass').aclass.live("click",  function (e) {
$('.aclass').aclass.css("color", "#47b2ed");
$(this).aclass.css("color", "red");
});

</script>0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it does not so. On the server side there is no action taken to present the links in different colors. It is only done on the client (your browser).

You are sending the information, which link is clicked to the server (via the href). On the server side you need to use a programming framework such as PHP to send different HTML code back to the client in regard of the clicked links information

Example with PHP

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
?>
<a class="aclass<?php print $id == 1 ? ' active' : ''?>"  href="~/product/explain?id=1"> item1</a>
<a class="aclass<?php print $id == 2 ? ' active' : ''?>"   href="~/product/explain?id=2"> item2</a>
<a class="aclass<?php print $id == 3 ? ' active' : ''?>"  href="~/product/explain?id=3"> item3</a>
```

And add the color red to the CSS

```
aclass.active {
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How abt this one :-

```
a.aclass:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a.aclass:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a.aclass:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a.aclass:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ux47e/1/)